# How to create a FlexTable with thead and tbody

Tags: java, gwt, flextable

How to create this simplest table in GWT FlexTable?

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The documentation of FlexTable it's not clear about creating tables with `thead` and `tbody`. Anyone could help? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the *flexibility* of `FlexTable` and need to add a `thead` element, you can achieve it by manipulating `TableElement`. It is quite low-level, but id does what you need.

Here is how to get a DOM structure given in your example:

```
FlexTable table = new FlexTable();

table.setText(0, 0, "January");
table.setText(0, 1, "$100");
table.setText(1, 0, "February");
table.setText(1, 1, "$80");

com.google.gwt.user.client.Element oldElement = table.getElement();
com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element element = (com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element) oldElement;
TableElement tableElement = (TableElement) element;
TableSectionElement tHead = tableElement.createTHead();

TableRowElement row = tHead.insertRow(0);
row.insertCell(0).setInnerText("Month");
row.insertCell(1).setInnerText("Savings");

RootPanel.get().add(table);
```

Note that `table.getElement();` returns deprecated `com.google.gwt.user.client.Element`. It extends `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element` and so does `TableElement`. Once all casts are done you can add rows and cells to `thead`.

Here is the result (tested with GWT 2.7 on Chrome):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.
Why do you need it ?

Comment: Well, I do not really need to do this that way, but it's a basic structure of table and it should be easy to do that with GWT. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Using FlexTable this is certainly not possible.
But maybe the thing you really want is a DataGrid or a CellTable ?